# Как получить размер передаваемых по сети данных?

Tags: сеть, передача-данных, протоколы

Собственно вводные данные. Пишу протокол прикладного уровня в качестве транспорта используется `TCP`. И столкнулся с проблемой как узнать размер передаваемых данных?

Протокол выглядит примерно так:

Для данных сначала высчитывается хэш, все это зашифровывается и отправляется. Единственное решение которое я придумал, это передавать перед данными в фиксированном количестве байт *(например, в 4)* незашифрованный размер, но есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: Все правильно, надо самому передавать либо размер данных либо например в конце данных должен идти какой то признак, что при шифрованном потоке достаточно сложно сделать.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за ответ, тогда думаю вопрос можно закрыть.